# AWS CloudFront and ELB: requests doesn't reach backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

Get into quite strange trouble. Have an Cloudfront distribution with two origins: S3 and ELB.

I've set behaviors for Default (*) and the Custom (/test-request*).

On ELB side there is a rule to forward request from my domain to certain backend. Domain also added as an alias for cloudfront distribution.

But anytime I try to reach https://my.domain/test-request I've got... nothing. Looks like all request go to S3 content and never reach the backend I need.

I've already play with options on behavior side, read a lot of tutorials, but still no luck.

I'm not searching for clear answers, but at least I need direction of my research.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your Cloudfront distribution configuration is

- /test-request to your ELB as first priority
- Default (*) to your S3 as the catch-all
- my.domain is mapped to your Cloudfront's CNAME correctly

When you try to access my.domain/test-request, Cloudfront will match your cache behavior and forwards to your ELB, together with the path /test-request.

**Please note that it does NOT strip the /test-request path from your original request.**

Your ELB then forwards the original request to your application server, using the path /test-request.

Therefore, it's likely that your application does **not** expose any resource or API under the path /test-request, and the request fails as a result.

Also, since you are in this topic, please note that by default, Cloudfront does not forward query parameters or browser cookie to your custom origin which is ELB in your case. If you want to capture them, you need to configure the cache behavior properly.

Refs:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesQueryString